# how to add search mechanism through textboxs in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

Good day i need to add a searching/filtering mechanism in the asp grid view.I have three text boxes for making the searches and can it be done without hitting the database.
Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Try something first, and if you have a problem, post your code and your error here to get help.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you

[Multi-Column-Filter-GridView-With-Effective-Paging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/700874/Multi-Column-Filter-GridView-With-Effective-Paging#)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what  @ MikeSmithDev had commented on. But I would like to give you an idea on how to achieve this task. You could either use DevExpress gridview that is a more convenient and user friendly or if you still stick with asp.net grid view then try adding a textbox-button combination to the bottom of the grid (page footer). When entering the text and clicking on the consecutive button, the gridview data can be filtered.

Try this in your own ways and ideas, and still you get stuck, copy your code and ask another question. We will help you get to your answer.